# How to recode values of a variable based on the maxmium value in the variable, for hundreds of variables?

Tags: sas, data-manipulation

I want to recode the max value of a variable as 1 and 0 when it is not. For each variable, there may be multiple observations with the max value. The max value for each value is not fixed, i.e. from cycle to cycle the max value for each variable may change. And there are hundreds of variables, cannot "hard-code" anything.

The final product would have the same dimensions as the original table, i.e. equal number of rows and columns as a matrix of 0s and 1s.

This is within SAS. I attempted to calculate the max of each variable and then append these max as a new observation into the data. Then comparing down the column of each variable against the "max" observation... looking into examples of the following did not help:

1. SQL
2. Array in datastep
3. proc transpose
4. formatting

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: One way would be to calc the MAX of all variables in a PROC MEANS, output to a dataset with one record, and join that to your original dataset. Then you can use arrays to compare corresponding original values with the MAX value. After you finish you can just drop all the MAX value columns

Comment: Please show what you've tried so far. I suggest looking at PROC STDIZE for starters. But either 2 or 4 should have options that can work.

Comment: @CraigSrsen Can you explain a bit how to compare with the MAX value? I've attached the MAX to the dataset, but not sure how to compare.

Comment: You have 2 arrays - the array of original values A, and the array of column MAXes B. 'if A[i] = B[i] then A[i] = 1; else A[i] = 0;'  Although best practice would be to put the 1s and 0s in a third array C and not overwrite your original data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version done with SQL:

The idea is that we first calculate the maximum. The Latter select. Then we join the data to original and the outer the case-select specifies if the flag is set up or not.

```
data begin; 
  input var value; 
  cards; 
1 1
1 2
1 3
1 2.5
1 1.7
1 3
2 34
2 33
2 33
2 33.7
2 34
2 34
  ; run;


proc sql; 
create table result as
  select a.var, a.value, case when a.value = b.maximum then 1 else 0 end as is_max from 
  (select * from begin) a 
  left join 
  (select max(value) as maximum, var from begin group by var) b 
  on a.var = b.var
; 
quit;
```

Comment: You could simplify by eliminating the join.  You could even remove the CASE since SAS evaluates boolean expressions as 0 or 1. `(value=max(value)) as value`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid "hard-code" you need to use some code generation.

First let's figure out what code you could use to solve the problem. Later we can look into ways to generate that code.

It is probably easiest to do this with PROC SQL code.  SAS will allow you to reference the MAX() value of a variable. Also note that SAS evaluates boolean expressions to 1 (TRUE) or 0 (FALSE).  So you just want to generate code like:

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
  select var1=max(var1) as var1
       , var2=max(var2) as var2
  from have
;
quit;
```

To generate the code you need a list of the variables in your source dataset.  You can get those with PROC CONTENTS but also with the metadata table (view) DICTIONARY.COLUMNS (also accessible as SASHELP.VCOLUMN from outside PROC SQL).

If the list of variables is small then you could generate the code into a single macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
select catx(' ',cats(name,'=max(',name,')'),'as',name)
  into :varlist separated by ','
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE'
  order by varnum
;
create table want as 
  select &varlist
  from have
;
quit;
```

The maximum number of characters that will fit into a macro variable is 64K. So long enough for about 2,000 variables with names of 8 characters each.

Here is little more complex way that uses PROC SUMMARY and a data step with a temporary array.  It does not really need any code generation.

```
%let dsin=sashelp.class(obs=10);
%let dsout=want;
%let varlist=_numeric_;

proc summary data=&dsin nway ;
  var &varlist;
  output out=summary(drop=_type_ _freq_) max= ;
run;

data &dsout;
  if 0 then set &dsin;
  array vars &varlist;
  array max [10000] _temporary_;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    set summary ;
    do _n_=1 to dim(vars);
      max[_n_]=vars[_n_];
    end;
  end;
  set &dsin;
  do _n_=1 to dim(vars);
    vars[_n_]=vars[_n_]=max[_n_];
  end;
run;
```

Results:

```
Obs    Name       Sex    Age    Height    Weight

  1    Alfred      M      0        1         1
  2    Alice       F      0        0         0
  3    Barbara     F      0        0         0
  4    Carol       F      0        0         0
  5    Henry       M      0        0         0
  6    James       M      0        0         0
  7    Jane        F      0        0         0
  8    Janet       F      1        0         1
  9    Jeffrey     M      0        0         0
 10    John        M      0        0         0
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid SQL for other reasons, but it should work in the interim. Also simplified the problem, but I think this may work. Essentially rather than comparing it to the MAX, I'm comparing it to some reserve code that is related to the MAX.

Comment: You could possibly update the question with a description of this different problem.  Or start a new question.

Comment: Added a version using PROC SUMMARY and DATA STEP.

Comment: Thanks @Tom, the comparison using array is what I couldn't figure out and it is very helpful. I think I can swap out the max for external specifications as needed.